# Is it possible to create a 'view all' page in Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

I've tried creating pages using the 'standard layout' and 'custom layout' but neither allows the use of the `{block:Posts}` variable(s).  I need to re-create essentially the archive page but with some custom css.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

If I try `$("#someDiv").load("/archive", "#content");` the whole page formatting gets screwed up. Is there a way to load just the `<a>` tags into a div on my custom page?

Or would it be possible to use the API entirely client side to accomplish this?

Any ideas on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with two possible solutions if anyone else finds themselves stuck on this.  I abandoned this first one before finalizing it, so it's a bit rough but a good start.  It uses the API to load photos (that was all I needed) as you scroll down the page.

```
<script>
  function getPhotos(offset){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/[tumblr].tumblr.com/posts?api_key=[key]&offset="+offset,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(results){
        loaded += 20;
        total = results.response.blog.posts;
        if(total > loaded){
          results.response.posts.forEach(function(post){
            post.photos.forEach(function(photo){
                $("#photos ul").append("<li class='"+post.tags.join(" ")+"'><img src='"+photo.alt_sizes[0].url+"'></li>");
                $("#photos").imagesLoaded(function(){
                    $("#photos").masonry({
                        itemSelector: 'li'
                    });
                });
            });
          });
          if($("#photos ul").height() < $(window).height()){
            getPhotos(loaded);
          } 
        }
      }
    });
  }

  loaded = 0;

  getPhotos(loaded);

  $(window).scroll(function() {
     if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
         getPhotos(loaded);
     }
  });
</script>
```

What I've ended up doing is just using an iframe with a custom stylesheet appended to the head.

html:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://[remote location]/frame.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="photos">
    <iframe name="frame1" id="frame1" src="http://[tumblr]/archive" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

frame.js:

```
$(function(){
  function insertCSS(){
    var frm = frames['frame1'].document;
    var otherhead = frm.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    if(otherhead.length != 0){
        var link = frm.createElement("link");
      link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
      link.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
      link.setAttribute("href", "http://[remote location]/frame.css");
      otherhead.appendChild(link);
      setTimeout(function(){$("#frame1").show();}, 200);
      clearInterval(cssInsertion);
    }
  }

  cssInsertion = setInterval(insertCSS, 500);
  //setTimeout(insertCSS, 1000);

  $(window).scroll(function() {
     if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && $("#frame1").height() < 50000) {
         $("#frame1").css("height", "+=1000px");
     }
  });
});
```

frame.css (stylesheet appended into iframe)

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#nav_archive{
    display: none;
}
.heading{
    display: block !important;
}
.old_archive #content{
    margin: 0 auto 0;
}
```

style.css (stylesheet on page where iframe is located)

```
#frame1{
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```